# Three divs unable to align horisontally

Tags: html, css

I found another post here with someone having the same problem as I, except with images. That solution was already similar to my existing code and I could still not fix the issue.

I have 3 divs that has needs to be positioned like this:

```
____ ____ ____
     ____ 
     ____
```

The middle div is a div containing basically just clean text and HR tags. Preferably I would like the two divs floated left/right to be in a fixed position.
Instead of pasting alot of code in this post, I've uploaded the files (just an index and a style.css) to this place: orebropartiet.se/dev/k

As you can see it looks terrible. Why?

Comment: Please don't include links to your code in posts (especially as a new user) because they could be links to spam or malware. Just post the code here, but only post the code that's relevant to the question.

Comment: @user3630404 you find a way to solve it from my answer

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't think cluttering this post with my entire html page would be appreciated. Didn't know either what was relevant or not, maybe there was something I missed somewhere etc.. noted though!

Comment: @user3630404 Not a problem; if it's a question where it would be useful, though (i.e. one that involves a bit of tinkering), a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) might be helpful, but you still need to include the code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#contain {
    width: 24%;
    line-height: 16px;
    float: left;
}
#middle {
width: 50%;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}
#contain2 {
    width: 24%;
    line-height: 16px;
    float: left;
}
```

Just make them all float left, it will work fine as your container #all has 100% width. 
To make the divs responsive for different screen resolutions, i have added width in terms of percentage.

```
<div id="all">

<div id="contain" style="text-align: center;"> 

    <p class="bigger">#utmanajimmie ni med!</p>
    <hr width="250px" size="1px" color="#D88031">
    <p class="bigger">Dela?&nbsp;  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://utmanajimmie.se">facebook</a> | <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=De%20b%C3%A4sta%20motdemonstranterna%20just%20nu!%20%23utmanajimmie%20www.utmanajimmie.se">twitter</a> </p> 
    <hr width="250px" size="1px" color="#D88031">

</div>

<div id="middle">

    <h3>Bästa motdemonstranterna just nu:</h3>
    <h1>Uppsala</h1>
    <p>Kul text här</p>

</div> <!-- wrapper -->

        <div id="contain2" style="margin-top: 50px">

        <fieldset id="contact_form">
        <legend><p class="bigger">Nominera och rösta!</p></legend>
        <div id="result"></div>
            <label for="name"><span></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Namn">
            </label>

            <label for="email"><span></span>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-post">
            </label>

            <label for="message"><span></span>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Din röst eller nominering! Motivera gärna med beskrivning och nyhetsartiklar."></textarea>
            </label>

            <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
            <button class="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Skicka</button>
            </label>
        </fieldset>

        </div> <!-- contain2 -->

</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Apparently changing from pixels to % made it magically work itself out, even with float:right on the right div. Very appreciated! Stared at this for almost an hour before coming here.

Comment: you are welcome :) Yes when you mention the divs in percentage, float:right or float:left to the last div doesn't make much difference other than padding between the middle div and last one. You will notice the gap when you give some background color for each of those divs

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I switched alot of the height/width measures to % now, it seems to work better overall. I also used the background-color to see where divs are positioned in my favor, and made the left floated box and the middle one "connected" through different colors! the same link I provided in my original post is updated with the new look.

Thanks for the help again, % worked so much smoother!